# How to delete specific push notification from API server

Tags: php, android, cordova, firebase, firebase-notifications

I am using [this PHP script](https://github.com/adhishlal/Firebase-PHP/blob/master/sendnotification.php) for sending a notification to **Firebase**:

```php
...
$fields = [
    'to' => DEVICE_TOKEN,
    'notification' => [
        'title'     => "Title",
        'body' => 'notification body',
        'tag' => 'tag',
    ],
];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
...
```

and it is properly popping on my **android**. I can also edit the notification using `tag` property

But **how can I delete notification**? If someone read it in browser for example, I need to delete this notification from other devices.

I tried to send empty `body` in edited notification, but doesn't work.

On the **Cordova** frontend I'm using [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase) and I am not sure if the problem is on backend or frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible to delete a notification message once it was sent to the device over the Firebase API.

One possible solution I see is to create a POST notification once the user sees the message to send it to your backend which sends a new notification with a specific "flag" and dosen't show this new notification because of the "flag" (you implement an if check in your app). And when device reads that flag it removes the notification based on the "flag". You do that with `cancel()` which is in `NotificationManager`. [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int))

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is using Device Group option of Firebase.

In that way you can easily register multiple devices of same user under a unique key. So when you send a push notification to that user on two different devices (for example a browser and a smartphone), the user read the notification from one device and it magically disappear from the other one.

It's very simple to do if you are already into the cordova and Firebase world.

Here's the reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/device-group